# Algorithm that round floating numbers like this

Tags: algorithm, assembly, floating-point, sse

the questions is: i've got large amount of floating numbers(double 64bits), for each number, i will keep 6 digitals.

For example, the original number is 231.123456789, after process, it should be 231.123457.

i have implemented this function, but it runs very slow. is there any faster Algorithms. May be it can take advantages of the SSE, or based on something deep, i mean it can reflect the essence of the floating point numbers, not like my superficial implemention(below).

```
void Round6(double& dVal)
{
    dVal *= 1000000;
    dVal += 0.5;
    dVal = floor(dVal);
    dVal /= 1000000;
}
```

Comment: Show the implementation.

Comment: floats are fundamentally base 2, so rounding to a decimal representation like this is inherently approximate.  (i.e. there is no way to exactly represent these numbers in floats)  What are you using this for?  How much performance are you getting?  How much do you need?

Comment: `b /= 1000000`, when `b` is of type `int`, to obtain 6 decimal digits? You might as well provide the code you really have written, it does not help serious discussion to deal with approximative pseudo-code.

Comment: source code has been added.

Comment: I tested my whack routine shown below and it runs about 3.5X faster than what you provided.  Your mileage may vary!

Comment: @Jim In your test, you use `printf("%f")` to print the result, and the default precision of the `%f` format is 6 decimal places. Your test only proves that `printf()` works. Note that if your code worked, you would have invented a method to convert from binary to decimal quickly with only bit manipulations. I am sorry to tell you that this is highly unlikely. Multiplication and divisions by powers of ten are an irreducible part of conversion to base 10, as dwelch pointed out in his answer. You could simulate them with bit operations, but that wouldn't be faster.

Comment: I see the error of my ways.  It's a valid BINARY truncation, but not a decimal one.

Comment: @Jim Yes, your method can be used to compute the nearest integer to a floating-point number, for instance: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/03/nearbyintf2

Comment: Is there an solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do base 10 math with a base 2 fpu, I think you have it pretty close to minimal code.  You will need to do the math in base 10 fashion which is what you have done, multiply, round up, convert to integer to strip the remaining fraction, and then convert back.  as mention your b/= wont work since b is an int you lose the fraction, need to make that last divide floating point.

Comment: I dunno.  Assuming my notion works, I have one assign, one AND, one conditional, then another AND and possibly one fp add.  No multiplies and no divides.

Comment: @Jim The code in your answer does not do anything close to what is asked.

Comment: @PascalCuoq  Bah!  That's a big harsh.  It's close.  It probably doesn't work, but it's close.  As in the ballpark.

Comment: Oh, yes, those fuctions may be very fast, but the result is wrong. it  maybe useful if i have a Quantum Computer whose registers have 10 status instead of 2.